# Lasso coefficients and penalization impact

Tags: lasso, regularization

What is the correct interpretation of the coefficients from a lasso regression if you standardize ((x-mean(x))/sd(x) the predictor variables?

If you observer 4.2 for variable A and -1.2 for variable B does that mean a 1 standard deviation increase in variable A is associated with 4.2 increase in the response variable? and a 1 SD increase in B is associated with a decrease of 1.2 in the response?

I've seen some comments that the lasso regression coefficients (when the variables are standardized) are NOT interpretable because they are penalized coefficients. Do you agree with that or the interpretation above?

Comment: What do the values here represent? The coefficients?

Comment: It's true that you should standardize coefficient before penalizing, but nothing stops us from un-standardizing the coefficient after estimation in order to interpret them in the usual way. Though Lasso is a different estimator than OLS, the linear model remains the exact same, so we can still interpret model parameters per usual.

Comment: You say standardize the coef but the variable not coef is standardized. So if you observer 4.2 coefficient for variable A and -1.2 coefficient for variable B does that mean a 1 standard deviation increase in variable A is associated with 4.2 increase in the response variable? and a 1 SD increase in B is associated with a decrease of 1.2 in the response?

Comment: The interpretation is identical as with a regular linear model, all regularization does is (potentially) shrink the coefficients by some amount. If you standardize the data you would interpret these as standardized coefficients. Why do you want to interpret the coefficients of a penalized model?

Comment: So if you observer 4.2 coefficient for variable A and -1.2 coefficient for variable B does that mean a 1 standard deviation increase in variable A is associated with 4.2 increase in the response variable? and a 1 SD increase in B is associated with a decrease of 1.2 in the response?

Comment: @jhn5v78 "variable not coef is standardized" it turns out that the effect of scaling $x$ by $a$ is to scale the coefficient by $\frac{1}{a}$, so these notions are linked. You should try fitting a (standard OLS) linear regression on $y$ to $X$ and $y$ to $aX$ and observe how the coefficient changes to get this to really sink in. But if you really want to interpret these things on the standard deviation scale, that is correct (and given how many times you've written that same passage it seems you do :)).

Comment: PS welcome to the site, and note that in order for me to be notified of your comment you have to "at me" using the @ sign and then my name.